# How to use a package script under a different platform?

Tags: npm, webpack

I have to have this line package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "default_linux": "export NODE_ENV=default&& export NODE_MINIFIED=false&& webpack",
  "default_windows": "set NODE_ENV=default&& set NODE_MINIFIED=false&& webpack",
  "default_linux_min": "export NODE_ENV=default&& export NODE_MINIFIED=true&& webpack",
  "default_windows_min": "set NODE_ENV=default&& set NODE_MINIFIED=true&& webpack",
},
```

But to run a not very nice to think about each version separately and so as to correctly configure scripts for different platforms to make it as a team, not ..?

```
$ npm run default_linux #  frontend assembly under linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) package on npm. It allows you to use unix style scripts, and handles all the cross-platform issues. It works for linux and windows, but I haven't tested it for Mac. Also, there's no need for `export`.

After you install cross-env, you can replace your scripts field with this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=default NODE_MINIFIED=false webpack",
    "build-min": "cross-env NODE_ENV=default NODE_MINIFIED=true webpack",
},
```

Comment: WARNING in NODE_MINIFIED environment variable is undefined.

Comment: splincode web-developer: Ah yes, I forgot: the whole thing needs to be single command when your run the webpack command, so the `&&`s need to disappear. I've updated the answer accordingly.